# Enable CAPTCHA on magento 1.9

Tags: magento, captcha

How did I enable the CAPTCHA?

My Customer Configuration doesn't have a CAPTCHA option, the last configuration option is "Address Templates"

I am using the RWD Theme and i have already copied `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/captcha.xml` to `app/design/frontend/rwd/MY_THEME/layout/captcha.xml`

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

CAPTCHA is the perfect option to enable in frontend, backend or contact us to prevent any possible spam.

There are three sections in which we can enable captcha:

1. Frontend (checkout, login, register)
2. Backend (use for admin login page, prevent auto-logging)
3. contact form page (prevent auto submission/spam)

For a detailed information to enable CAPTCHA on all of these above mentioned fields, follow this tutorial:  https://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-enable-captcha-in-magento